# Can I use javascript to dynamically change a video's source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html

How can I change a video's source using JS?

```
<video id="myVideoTag" width="670" height="377" autoplay="true" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.test.com/test.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Comment: What should be dynamic and what's the problem? Do you have any Javascript experience?

Comment: I want make a playlist, so after first video finished, play second video.

Comment: I have js experience, I have done ended event like this

  $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){ 
    // ??? How to play next
  });

Comment: That snippet is jQuery. I've added a jQuery tag.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sure,

1. You can set the `src` attribute on the `source` element:

   ```
   document.querySelector("#myVideoTag > source").src = "http://example.com/new_url.mp4"
   ```

   Or using jQuery instead of standard DOM methods:

   ```
   $("#myVideoTag > source").attr("src", "http://example.com/new_url.mp4"​​​​)​
   ```
2. Then you need to call the `load` method on the video element:

   `videoElement.load()`

Comment: Changing the src attribute of the source tag does nothing. Set it on the video tag directly.

Comment: i voted up, but this answer is actually wrong. there is no way to change the `source` tags: you need to change the `src` attribute in the `video` tag. this is the best solution i found so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5371478/950704

Comment: Worked for me, just remember to call `videoElement.load()` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: "> source" give javascript error, How can remove this

Answer (score 21):

I have faced this problem several times and based on previous experience and digging I can suggest these options:

- **replace video tag completely**

yes, just re-insert `<video>` element with new sources. It's straightforward, but effective approach. Don't forget to re-initialize event listeners.

---

- **assign video URL to** `video.src`

this I saw a lot in answers here, on stackoverflow, and also in sources on github.

```
var video = document.getElementById('#myVideo');
video.src = newSourceURL;
```

It works, but you cannot provide browser options to choose from.

---

- **call** `.load()` **on video element**

according to [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp) you can update `src` attributes for `<video>`'s `<source>` tags and then call `.load()` to changes take effect:

```
<video id="myVideo">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<script>
    var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
    sources[0].src = anotherMp4URL;
    sources[1].src = anotherOggURL;
    video.load();
</script>
```

Nevertheless [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5235145/1381288) it's said that there're problems in some browsers.

I hope it will be useful to have this all in one place.

Answer (score 5):

I have run into the same problem. According to this thread:

[changing source on html5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

it is not possible to change the src of the source tag. you will have to use src of the video tag itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is working

```
<video id="videoplayer1" width="240" height="160" controls>
    <source id="video_res_1" src="" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

and in the javascript

```
document.getElementById("video_res_1").src = "my video url.ogv";
document.getElementById("videoplayer1").load();
```

The key is the .load() function that reloads the video player.

Comment: Thanks! Using the load() method worked for me after changing the src of the source tags with js. play() did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to change the `src` attribute of a source element, according to [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element:the-source-element-12) spec note.

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is
> already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To
> change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media
> element directly

So lets say you have:

```
<audio>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

You can modify the media src like so:

```
<audio src='./second-src'/>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Campbell has provided the correct solution, a more complete solution to the 'playlist specific' question at hand (as noted in the comments) is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151606/setattribute-and-video-src-for-changing-video-tag-source-not-working-in-ie9). This solution can be applied to all video formats if implemented correctly (I have used [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) in order to detect which source will play for a given browser, combined with the solution above).

This solution will work (and has been tested) for changing videos in HTML5 video tags in ALL HTML5 browsers, including IE8.

Comment: Why the downvote? The solution link provided in my answer is accurate and there is no reason to repost the entire solution from the other post here...if you are going to downvote, explain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This javascript changes the src of the source tag.
https://jsfiddle.net/a94zcrtq/8/

```html
<script>
  function toggle() {
            if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
                $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
                document.getElementById("source").src = "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4";
                document.getElementById("videoPlayer").load();
            } else {
                $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
                document.getElementById("source").src = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
                document.getElementById("videoPlayer").load();
            }
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it should work and please adjust attribute name and id as per your need

html code below

```
<video controls style="max-width: 90%;" id="filePreview">                        
    <source type="video/mp4" id="video_source">
</video>
```

js code below

```
   $("#fileToUpload").change(function(e){
        var source = $('#video_source');
        source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        source.parent()[0].load();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that dynamically creating and appending the child `source` elements did the trick.

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector('.my-video');
var videoSources = ["video.mp4","video.webm"]
if (videoElement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < videoSources.length; i++) {
        var sourceTag = document.createElement("source");
        sourceTag.type = "video/" + videoSources[i].split('.')[1];
        sourceTag.src = videoSources[i];
        videoElement.appendChild(sourceTag);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other solutions didn't work for me, here's what I did:

```
 <video width="400" controls id="the_id_of_your_video_here">
  <source src="path_to_first_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>

<button type="button" name="button" onclick="changeVid()">Click me to change the video</button>

<script>
function changeVid(){
  var video =  document.getElementById("the_id_of_your_video_here");
  video.src = 'path_to_second_video.mp4'; // Make sure to not use ..\ like in HTML but ../ if you have to give a more complex file path like: '../../myVideoFolder/myVideo.mp4'
  video.load();
}
</script>
```

Nothing else is needed to get this solution running - unless I messed up somehow...