# html5 videoplayer@ipad: changing the video

Tags: ipad, html, video

i'm [still working on my html5 videoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag) w/ flashplayer fallback. it is now part of a bigger kind of widget, that encapsulates tabs, sliders, carousels (extensively using jquery)

focussing on the videoplayer: the user can (repeatedly) pick videos to play from a carousel . once a carousel item is clicked, i put a div w/ a fitting background-image over my videoplayer, so as to have a splashimage working the same for every client. that 'selfmade splashimage' and the current frontitem of the carousel (which was just clicked) then are bound to the load() method of the video. obviously there's a lot of stuff happening in between: i check for support of `<video>` and support of formats (mp4, ogv). i also fade in and out a bunch of stuff. that was a short version of it. and it's all working pretty okay on all the browsers i tested. it IS somewhat working on the ipad as well BUT:::

when i click my splashimage/playbutton ( -> triggering the load() method) the ipad wont play nor load my video RIGHT AWAY. the videoplayer stays black. however, when i click (trigger load()) a few more times, at some point it will start to work as planned.

the ipad works fine on the [w3 html5 video events page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html). so i copied that page for my purpose, replaced a video with one of my videos and it gives me the FAULTY behaviour. so the problem are my videos, aren't they? the videos are currently hosted on a non-streaming server, is that the problem? my knowledge on that subject is really narrow.

sorry for not including any code and talking very general and abstract about the whole thing but i hope it suffices.

EDIT::: problem (kind of) solved. apparently the server the videos were hosted on, was causing the problems -_-

Answer (score 1):

Could it have something to do with this: [how to get your HTML5 MP4 video file to play before being fully downloaded](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/03/html5/how-to-get-your-html5-mp4-video-file-to-play-before-being-fully-downloaded) as it could be downloading the video, hence the wait.

Comment: thanks a lot, that actually DID help me with a big problem i had in IE9. unfortunately it didn't solve my ipad problem. working on that...