# How to add more than one video source with JS?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, mediaelement.js

EDIT: I think i haven't explained myself correctly.

I need to set **(via javascript)** more than one video source to my video.

For example set:

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4"></source>
<source type="video/ogg" src="video.ogg"></source>
```

is there any way to do this? also if i only have a video that the currently web browser doesn't support will it fallback to flash?

Im using mediaelementjs (and jquery) (in a few words, what i need is to click an image and magically the browser supported video (another video) must load).

thanks!

Comment: your example doesn't seem to be showing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah man, you can set more than one source so, the browser will load just the supported source , and in case that it doesn't support HTML5 video, it will load the embed tag (flash)

Here an example:

```
<video poster="myvideo.jpg" controls>
 <source src="myvideo.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="myvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
 <embed src="/to/my/video/player"></embed>
</video>
```

**--- edited ---**

So, you wanna to add more source tags dynamically. Like an onclick function. You have some options:

1. You can just change the `src` attribute in video element;
2. You can change the `src` attribute of each source element;
3. You can create more source elements and append all to the video element;

In any of these cases, you will need to run the `load` and `play` functions of video element after changes or add sources;

PS: remember that only one source will be played, the one that the browser can read. So you can't add a lot of videos (like different videos, instead differents extensions) and expect that a playlist will be created;

More questions about it:

- [Changing source on HTML5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)
- [Changing video being played in HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Comment: If using mediaelement.js this is the right approach but the embed is unnecessary. The library handles that.

Comment: This is just the way to use video element without javascript handlers :]

Comment: I haven't correctly explained myself. Please re-read my original question.

Comment: @Pablini, do you wanna add a video tag or more sources tags?

Comment: @RafaelVerger I want to add more than one source tag after clicking a thumb (for example)