# change a html5 video source using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video on my webpage like so:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
<video id="video1" width="960" controls autoplay>
    <source src=static/media/Wreck_It_Ralph_Trailer.mp4 type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support html5 video
</video>
```

and I want to change the source of the video using jquery/javascript. I have this code but it doesn't work

```
$('source').attr({'src':'static/media/Here_Comes_The_Boom_Official_Trailer.mp4'})
```

Can someone say why this isn't working or suggest a correct way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the link by Mic I needed an extra line of code

```
a=document.getElementById('video1')
a.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('video1').src = 'static/media/Here_Comes_The_Boom_Official_Trailer.mp4';
```

which just changes the video player's source directly, without fiddling with the DOM elements.