# Add video link to video html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I would like to enter a url in a text box and be able to mirror that url to the video html.
Example url: http://www.example.com/video.mp4

I am thinking this should be possible using js.
This is how the html would originally look like

```
<input type="text" value="" />
<video width="320" height="240">
    <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
</video>
```

After entering the url the html would look like this.

```
<input type="text" value="http://www.example.com/video.mp4" />
<video width="320" height="240">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.example.com/video.mp4"/>
</video>
```

I would then extend this to support all three video formats with three text fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing source on html5 video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Me7UB/1/

Comment: @askovpen Your solution works great. I changed it a bit so the go button was not needed. http://jsfiddle.net/Me7UB/4/ Please answer the question and I will select yours as the best answer.