# Audio tag change audio quality while playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm currently working on an audio player based on the html5 audio tag using javascript for a project.
I am asked to handle audio quality (as you would see on YouTube for videos).
I guess, the only way to do it is to have multiple source files (for instance a SQ mp3 + HQ mp3 / SQ ogg + HQ ogg + wav) and change it with javascript, but I was wondering how, and if it was the best option.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: you compare apples to oranges. audio uses FAR less bandwidth than youtube videos (especially hd), so the demand/need is not the same.

Comment: Well, maybe, but I was talking about the principle, I'd like to add a button triggering the change of the audio file. Don't you think it's the right way to do it ?
(Audio quality really matters in that project I'm working on)

Comment: Doing it seamlessly would be a far more complex problem, but the simplest solution would be to: 1) keep track of current audio time. 2) on quality change, switch source to the desired one 3) play the new source from the last measured time

Answer (score 0):

Manual selection of changing the quality is just a matter of:

1. Saving the `currentTime` in a variable.
2. setting the audio `src` to the URL of a different audio (with the same content at a different quality).
3. Setting the `currentTime` to the value in the variable.
4. Playing the audio.

And these all you can do with javascript or jquery.

To Change `src` to  high quality file,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag) will help you.