# Changing video source in a web player

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a web player and it is supposed to change the video source by the click of a button, but it does not work, I've tried everything.

```
myVideo.src = "http://www8.cs.umu.se/kursmaterial/html5/mediafiler/WaterBalloon2.mp4";
```

This part is supposed to have 2 video sources, 1 for mp4 and 1 for ogv, which I can't seem to figure out how to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pqb3H/

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing source on html5 video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1")[0];` inside the `getVideo()` function,

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqb3H/1/