# Using javascript functions from html file in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a javascript (inside of an html file) to load and reproduce the videos by streaming in my android app, so I am trying to use a webview to display the video. My problem is that the file is not in a server, but it is a project resource (I mean it is in the project directory, exactly in `/res/raw/video_player.html`) and I want to call a specific function of the javascript passing the video url as param.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We did something very similar but with Cordova(PhoneGap), and there was a plugin for playing the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wish to set the `src` attribute of your video tag. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag) for how to do that from JavaScript.

To play video in full-screen mode the WebView passes the URL to the Android media player and the file:///android_asset scheme is something only the WebView supports. If you're assigning an http(s) URL then you're fine and don't need to do anything else, otherwise I guess one way would be to unpack the video to your data folder and use a 'regular' file:// URL.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The javascrpt is inside of an html file, and the video is reproduced in the html, I am not using MediaPlayer

Comment: @Tony_craft - the video is embedded in the html? how?

Comment: with a video tag inside of the body of the htlm:
    `<body onload="init()">
        <video src="" ...>
        </video>
    </body>`

Comment: But is it necessary to use a media player also? I have seen in other examples they don't use a media player (or it seems that)

Comment: @Tony_craft - the WebView uses a media player internally.

Comment: @Tony_craft - no, you don't need to do anything with it.