# Changing Video src using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the video scr  when play button is click 
my html is

```
<video class="mvideo" controls autoplay="autoplay">
    <source class="video" src="path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<button class="button">Play</button>
```

and my jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".video").attr("src","videos/Funny Cats.mp4");
    })
});
```

Comment: Try `$(".video source").prop("src","videos/Funny Cats.mp4");`

Comment: So what happens when you try that? Errors? @Satpal, there is no element with the class video that has a descendant source element. `<source>` *is* the element with that class.

Comment: @Satpal the class video is the source tag

Comment: This approach will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5371478/921204

Comment: Do you have more code? because what you have should work http://jsfiddle.net/2WDfB/

Answer (score 0):

The only way dynamic sources are going to work is if you apply them directly to the video tag eg:

```
<video class="mvideo" controls autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<button class="button">Play</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $("video").attr("src","videos/Funny Cats.mp4");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xEMzm/2/

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
        var video = $(".video").get(0);
        $(video).attr("src","a");
    alert($(video).attr("src"));
})
```

This way you can use methods like: volume and others. Using jQuery Object you can't.

Comment: it changes the src but new video it not play