# How can I zoom into video and switch streaming of videos in the same HTML5 player?

Tags: html, video-streaming, video.js

I have video that will be divided into 4 videos.

[image]

First the player will stream a lower resolution of the original video, then the user can zoom into the video to see more details, I need the player to stream one of the 4 videos - that's higher in resolution- based on where the user zoomed in.

How can I make that using VideoJS or any other video player ?

Comment: I think this may squeak in before reaching the line, but this sounds much more like a programing question than a video production question.  You may have better luck on an actual programming oriented QA site.

Comment: How do you split the video in four parts ?

Comment: @mootookoi Crop the video using ffmpeg  (https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching, this is the answer ...

For zooming into the video, you can follow this tutorial:  [Zooming and rotating for video in HTML5 and CSS3](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/)

For switch streaming of videos in the same player, you can make that by [changing the source on html5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag) and make some calculations to know where the user zoomed in and hence change the source video.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no response yet let me analyse the problem. This is by no means meant as a full answer, but other people will probably be able to answer parts of the problem:

*First the player will stream a lower resolution of the original video,*

This means you will need to create/use a video stream. There are plenty of plugins you can use for videostreaming, and depends on what you want. You can consider writing it yourself using for example C#'s System.IO objects and transforming the video in bytes(And putting it back together) The resolution would be easiest reached by just having a seperate video file for this step of the proces. (a lower resolution one used for streaming only)

*then the user can zoom into the video to see more details, I need the player to stream one of the 4 videos - that's higher in resolution- based on where the user zoomed in.*

So you need to trigger a zoom effect. This means you would need to detect zoom. This would be possible with Javascript in a webbrowser, if you want a browser based application. When that zoom is triggered you can retrieve what position the mouse is on the screen/in the div or on some sort of overlay. Depending on this position you could show another stream.

*How can I make that using VideoJS or any other video player ?*

Basically these steps above is how i would start looking into this specific case. Considering your VideoJS as a suggestion i assume this is browser based. This would probably mean using Javascript libraries, maybe combined with a server side language.

Thats as far as i can go. Maybe someone can pick up specific parts of the thing i wrote and help you a step further.

Have a nice day!