# How to change video source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

**HTML**

```
<video id="vdisk" controls poster="<?php echo $vposter ?>">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#vdisk source").attr("src", a); // a is a variable
console.log(a); //vdisk/01.mp4 - that's ok
```

When clicking on a "play" button nothing happens. There is no video in `vdisk`. The *console* is empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag

Comment: @SebastianWiteczek, there are 13 answers on your link, and there is no accepted any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the following...

```
$("#vdisk > source").attr("src", "new_video.mp4"​​​​)​
$("#vdisk")[0].load();
```