# Change video src using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have HTML code for two version of video, and I'm trying to change automaticly src of Video 2 with src of Video 1
Video 1 code:

```
<div id="TopPane5VideoPlayer_TopPlayer">
     <div id="TopPane5VideoPlayer_divInternalT">
           <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../player.swf?url=Root/Videos/3/17-08-2016/742393_ocean.mp4&amp;volume=90&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;previewImageUrl=../Root/Videos/3/17-08-2016/1920X955742393_ocean.jpg" width="1920" height="955" wmode="opaque" id="video_overlay">
            </object>
       </div>
```

Video 2:

```
<div class="sl-video">
<video autoplay>
        <source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"">
        <source src="video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"" />
            Video not supported.
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing source on html5 video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Comment: There are different kind of video datas. Do you want to have the object of Video1 in Video2?

Comment: #Tobias K. 1 , Yes, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('source')).map(x => x.remove())
document.querySelector('video').src = 
  document.querySelector('object').getAttribute('data').match(/url=([^&]+)&/)[1]
```