# Unable to play the Video in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

In my application i have a video tag for which i am appending src dynamically

this is my code

```
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="howtovideoimg" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>


$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#howtovideoimg').attr('src', 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4');
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/125/

Please let me know how to play the video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing source on html5 video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

Comment: "src" is not an attribute of the video tag. It needs a `<source>` tag within it. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp.

Comment: i Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/127/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
      var filepath = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
      filepath.src = "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video autobuffer controls autoplay id="videoPlayer">
  <source id="howtovideoimg" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new `<source>` element and then append it to video tag, it is simple to add the element dynamically in javascript, I put a example of js code, I think that can be of help for you...

```
function addSourceElement() {
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  source.src = 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
  source.type = 'video/mp4';

  video.appendChild(source);
  document.body.appendChild(video);
  video.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this kind of JS:

```
$('#howtovideoimg source').attr('src', "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
```

on this html:

```
<video id="howtovideoimg" autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I use to have a value in the source on page load (a white video) to avoid some weird behaviour on browser that do not consider the source attribute if it is empty