# Dynamic Fullscreen Background Video

Tags: javascript, web, video, dynamic, background

I have 2 fullscreen background videos that I want to change dynamically based on the time of day (ex. looping day video from 6 a.m. to 7 p.m. vs. looping night video from 7 p.m. to 6 a.m.). Currently, I'm commenting out the video that I don't want to play. Any advice on how to do this with JS would be much appreciated. (Videos are located in a folder called "video").

HTML:

```
<div class="video_contain">
            <!-- video day -->
            <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
                <source src="video/catbeats-loop-day-720p.m4v" poster="img/catbeats-day.gif" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

            <!-- video night -->
            <!-- <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
                <source src="video/catbeats-loop-night-720p.m4v" poster="img/catbeats-night.gif" type="video/mp4">
            </video> -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video_contain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

#video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create the src element with js depeding on the hour of the day and then append it to your video element, answer is inspired from this post.

[changing source on html5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag)

feel free to correct and improve this code.

```js
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var video = document.getElementById('video-background');
var source = document.createElement('source');

if (6 <= currentTime && currentTime < 7) {
source.setAttribute('src', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4');
video.appendChild(source);
video.play();
}
else {
    source.setAttribute('src', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4');
video.appendChild(source);
video.play();
}
```

```css
.video_contain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

#video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_contain">
            <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline></video>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. The only thing I changed was 

if (6 <= currentTime && currentTime < 7)

to

if (6 <= currentTime && currentTime < 19)
so that it works on a 24hr clock. Thanks!