# Setting a variable as video/audio source name

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<audio controls id="controls">
    <source src="Song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

JavaScript

```
var FileName = document.getElementById("controls").src
```

`alert(FileName)`
I am trying to make the alertbox say the source name (Song.mp3) not sure how to do this help!

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3732711/2853600 ? You can use document.querySelector("#controls > source").src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do:

```
var FileName = document.getElementById("controls").getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var FileName = $("source").attr('src');
```