# clojurescript html5 media elements

Tags: clojure, html5-video, clojurescript

I'm new to clojurescript/reagent and am testing out ideas for a media display app. 
At the moment I'm having problems with a few more specific elements of including html5 media components on my page and using their full features.

Example - including #t=10,10 at the end of a video source string(referenced here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) will sometimes work but only take the end range value. 
Same video element - using any attributes that aren't true/false will break compilation.  e.g :preload auto doesn't work whereas :fullscreen false does.

Is there a clojurescript way to handle these elements or is this more js interop territory?

Answer (score 1):

Since clojurescript will be compiled to JS eventually. Everything JS can do..clojurescript could do it equally well.

your "sometime work" issues are related to the nature of ReactJS ( Reagent is a wrapper of ReactJS ). Generally, you need to obtain the dom node of video tag to use most of the video tag's features.

### Related issues

[Video displayed in ReactJS component not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291688/video-displayed-in-reactjs-component-not-updating)

### Example

Source Code Example of how to interact with video tag under ReactJS.

https://github.com/eisneim/react-html5-video/blob/master/src/Video.js

You should provide the minimum case to produce the problem, so others could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and resources.  My simple example would be something like this - [:video {:width 200 :height 200 :src "video/video.mp4#t=15,60" :start:autoplay true :controls true :loop false :preload "auto" :fullscreen false }]. The #t= form at the end of should play a section of the video.  However, that is the part that only works sometimes.  Even when outside of a reagent component.

Comment: How would I be able to obtain the dom node?

Comment: the last two steps showing you how to get the dom https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-cookbook/blob/master/recipes/draggable/README.md