# Video source doesn't update on useState()

Tags: reactjs, video, state, refresh

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import rainClip from '../videos/rain.mp4';
import sunnyClip from '../videos/sunny.mp4';
import dullClip from '../videos/cloudy_black.mp4'
import '../App.css'
export default function Background({ weather }){
  const [clip, setClip] = useState(sunnyClip)
  console.log(clip)
  console.log('Background loaded')
  useEffect(() =>{
    if (weather[0].description.includes('дождь')){
      setClip(rainClip)
      console.log('Setted rain')
    }
    if (weather[0].description.includes('пасмурно')){
      setClip(dullClip)
      console.log('Setted dull')
    }
    if (weather[0].description.includes('ясно')){
      setClip(sunnyClip)
      console.log('Setted sun')
    }
  }, [weather])
 
    return(
        <video autoPlay loop muted
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: '-1',
          left: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, 0%)',
          position: 'absolute'
        }}
        >
        <source src={clip} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    )
}
```

I'm trying to make a weather app with a dynamic background that coincides with the current weather. However, my  element doesn't update video despite the clip state is updated.
Is it possible to dynamically change the video background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, manage to resolve it after reading another thread: [Video displayed in ReactJS component not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291688/video-displayed-in-reactjs-component-not-updating)

In react, we have to change the entire < video > element, and not just the < source > element, to see the video changes. Removing the source element, we can try this instead:

```js
...
return(
        <video autoPlay loop muted
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: '-1',
          left: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, 0%)',
          position: 'absolute'
        }}
        src={clip}
        type="video/mp4"
        />
        
   
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

put your video source inside src={} not in source.

```
 <video autoPlay loop muted
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          zIndex: '-1',
          left: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, 0%)',
          position: 'absolute'
        }}
        src={clip}
        type="video/mp4"
        />
```