# passing javascript variable to html5 video source

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to pass javascript variable as src to html5 video so that the video changes dynamically based on the js variable value. 
However I am not able to achieve it

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var path = "/api/Videos/mp4/";
        var filename = '@ViewBag.filename';
        var fullPath = path.concat(filename);
        document.getElementById('fullPath1').src = fullPath.toString();        
</script>
```

```html
<p><script type="text/javascript">document.write(fullPath)</script></p>
 <video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="fullPath1" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Please help me to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: you do not have any element with an id attribute set to `fullPath1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use javascript to dynamically change a video's source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732562/can-i-use-javascript-to-dynamically-change-a-videos-source)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for an element by id

```
document.getElementById('fullPath1').src = fullPath.toString();
```

but you haven't yet define any id:

```
<source src="fullPath1" type="video/mp4">
```