# change the default html5 video player in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, html5-video

Is it possible to change chromes default html5 video player to one like YouTube?
I would like to skip though a video by pressing the number keys, which works on YT and Flowplayer and so on

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely possible. You simply change the video source, as described here '[Can I use javascript to dynamically change a video's source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732562/can-i-use-javascript-to-dynamically-change-a-videos-source)'.

In combination with a keyboard shortcut library, like [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice), I am sure you can achieve your desired behaviour.