# How do I dynamically change multiple video sources using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to dynamically change the video source with the `onclick` event.

Here's the HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="1.jpg" id="bg">
    <source src="/static/media/1.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/static/media/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In `onclick` I generate a random link, then I change the source of the `<video>` element:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    var randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var srcmp4 = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/static/media/" + randint.toString() + ".mp4";
    document.getElementById('bg').src=srcmp4;
};
```

If I try to access the source element the same way, by assigning it an id:

```
<source id="webmid" src="/static/media/1.webm" type="video/webm">
```

I get null.

I want to dynamically change both .jpg, .webm, .mp4 links. How do I access and assign multiple source elements inside video tag via JS?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag

Comment: @dapizzaman many thanks, i ended up going with `.canPlayType` solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did some reading. First i tried deleting children of `video`, creating new `source` elements and appending to `video`, everything worked in page source, but view didn't render any changes. 
So i followed `.canPlayType` route to determine if client supports `.webm`, and if not -- assigning `mp4` `src` directly to `video` element.
Also added small fix so random generated numbers won't repeat. Random video loads when page is loaded and on click events afterwards. Here is the code, it's a mess:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="" id="bg">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
function randlink(a,b){
// generate random int in range of a,b. return str
var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*b)+a;
return "/static/media/"+c.toString();
}

//assign video new random src and poster on page load
window.onload = function(){
var bgvid = document.getElementById('bg');
var randbase = randlink(1,10);
bgvid.poster = randbase + ".jpg";
//check if webm, else mp4 src
if(bgvid.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"') != ""){
bgvid.src = randbase+".webm";
} else { bgvid.src = randbase+".mp4"}

//change src and poster on click
window.onclick = function() {
var randbase2 = randlink(1,10);
//check if unique
do{
randbase2 = randlink(1,10)
} while (randbase2 == randbase);
randbase = randbase2;
bgvid.poster = randbase2 + ".jpg";
var webmstr = ".webm";
//check if previous was webm, else mp4
if(bgvid.src.indexOf(webmstr) > 0){
bgvid.src = randbase2 +".webm";
}else{
bgvid.src = randbase2 +".mp4";
}}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The video tag is missing width, height, and controls attributes. Try this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" id="bg" autoplay loop controls>
  <source src="/static/media/1.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="/static/media/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Additionally here is the new js:

```
window.onclick = function() {
  var randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var srcmp4 = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/static/media/" + randint.toString() + ".mp4";
  var video = document.getElementById('bg');
  var source = document.getElementByTagName('source');
  source = srcmp4;
  video.load();
};
```

After changing that, the source seems to change according to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Amaredues/L7tj5Lrc/) test.

Comment: it assigns new `src` to the `<video>` itself without changing underlying `<source>` elements, i want to it to change .webm `src`, .mp4 `src`, and `poster` .jpg, but can't access these elements specifically, only the `<video>` tag itself, if i assign `id` to `<source>` and call it from js, it returns `null`

Comment: Did you take a look at @dapizzaman's link? I've edited to include the new js. The OP of that thread seems to do exactly this.

Comment: updated code does not target specific source(mp4 or webm), the only viable way i found is to remove children sources of video and append new generated ones, it works in page source, but does not update view. yes checked out the link, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered this before here: [Can I use javascript to dynamically change a video's source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732562/can-i-use-javascript-to-dynamically-change-a-videos-source/40330035#40330035)

You have to give the source tags different ids and then add another document.getElementById("source").src = "ANOTHER_SOURCE"; after the first one