# How to play a video in React whose path is obtained by parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I have an app which loads data from a json. That data could be a video, in which case it's rendered the next component:

```
export default function Video({ video }) {
  return (
    <>
      <video controls width="100%">
        <source src={require(video)} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
}
```

The param **video** has the path to the video, it's supossed to be located in a local folder on my app. When I try  to render the component **Video** with a valid param, I obtain the next error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'static/content/sample_video.mp4'`

Meanwhile, when I try to get the video directly from a string like this:
`

```
        <source src={require("static/content/sample_video.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
```

The video is rendered correctly. The parameter **video** has exactly the same string that I'm hardcoding in the require.

What should I do to render my video using the parameter?

Comment: I tried to put my video in the public folder so I don't need to using the require. Anyway, the problem is whit the require itself

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, you should trigger a load event for the video element whenever there's a new URL with a `useEffect` on a reference to the video element just like below.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Video({ video }) {
  const videoRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {    
    videoRef.current?.load();
  }, [video]);


  return (
    <>
      <video ref={videoRef} controls width="100%">
        <source src={require(video)} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
}
```

For more info see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47382850/19003871).

Comment: Yes using `.load()` is important but the main issue is first getting some file access, after that part, the code can move on to using the load command.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with the path that you have provided, check the folder structure or use the absolute path of the file, since I don't see any problems with your implementation