# How to change file upload text to image and upload the file and render to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 different upload button through which I need to upload the image and render to a div,I can able to render image on click of Upload button 1  but on click of  Upload button 2 I am not able to render the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".showonhover").click(function(){
            $("#selectfile").trigger('click');
        });
    });


var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]'); // see Example 4

input.onchange = function () {
  var file = input.files[0];

  drawOnCanvas(file);   // see Example 6
  displayAsImage(file); // see Example 7
};

function drawOnCanvas(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    var dataURL = e.target.result,
        c = document.querySelector('canvas'), // see Example 4
        ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      c.width = img.width;
      c.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };

    img.src = dataURL;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function displayAsImage(file) {
  var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
      img = document.createElement('img');

  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
  };

  img.src = imgURL;     
  // document.body.removeChild(img);
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(img);

}
function displayAsImage2(file) {
  var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
      img = document.createElement('img');

  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
  };

  img.src = imgURL;     
  // document.body.removeChild(img);
  document.getElementById("demo1").appendChild(img);

}

$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
});
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 20px;
  height:50px;
}
.imagediv {
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.imagediv .showonhover{
    background:red;
    padding:20px;
    opacity:0.9;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;  
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#upfile1 {
background:red;
    padding:20px;
    opacity:0.9;
    color:white;
    width: 10%;
    display:block;  
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer; 
}
#demo img,#demo1 img{
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>To an image "click on the image below"</h3>
<p>
<input type="file" id="file1" name="image" accept="image/*" capture style="display:none"/>
<span  id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />upload button1</span>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<div align="left" class="imagediv">
     <span>Or click here</span> 
            <span class="visibleimg"></span>
            <span class="showonhover">upload button2</span>
            <input id="selectfile" type="file" name="" style="display: none;" />
        </div>
    <script  src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your plunker, if you change the first file input to type "text" (so your CSS selector ignore it) the second button works just fine. You must have something crossed up in your selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I see is that [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns "the *first* Element within the document that matches the specified selector."

Since there are more than one input, I suggest using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return "a *list* of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors."

Below, I'm using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to bind the `onchange` listener to each input.

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".showonhover").click(function() {
    $("#selectfile").trigger('click');
  });
  $("#upfile1").click(function() {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
  });
});


var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {

  input.onchange = function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    displayAsImage(file);
  };

});


function displayAsImage(file) {

  var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
    img = document.createElement('img');

  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
  };

  img.src = imgURL;
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(img);

}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

input {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.imagediv {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.imagediv .showonhover {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#upfile1 {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#demo img,
#demo1 img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>To an image "click on the image below"</h3>
<p>
  <input type="file" id="file1" name="image" accept="image/*" capture style="display:none" />
  <span id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer">upload button1</span>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<div align="left" class="imagediv">
  <span>Or click here</span>
  <span class="visibleimg"></span>
  <span class="showonhover">upload button2</span>
  <input id="selectfile" type="file" name="" style="display: none;" />
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here I need one more help that same thing I need for video,whenever I click the button,video  tag should create and append into it.here I tried its working but when I click second time for other video,its not creating.Here is my plunker https://next.plnkr.co/edit/AH5uss8xKV1gHlNb?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [Can I use javascript to dynamically change a video's source?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215418/924299)

Comment: I have done in some different way,I have got whatever I want but here I am not able to add controls dynamically,is there any solution here is the plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/umHmYGJvT1a8WnVFxXAH?p=preview

Comment: @carreankush It seems to work for me. Controls are turned on.